# Delete .DS_STORE with File.Delete() C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently coding a C# console application which should get rid of the MacOS junk from an unzipped zip archive. Deleting the `__MACOSX` folder works fine but when I try to remove the `.DS_STORE` files with `File.Delete()`, the files don't get deleted. For example:

```
File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+ @"\.DS_Store");
```

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: No i don't get a exception ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` doesn't include a trailing slash, so you need to add it manually. Instead I would recommend using `Path.Combine`:

```
var pathToDelete = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ".DS_Store");
File.Delete(pathToDelete);
```